What questions can I ask the search committee for math tenure-track interviews?
I am in the job market this year for tenure-track positions in math. I have a Zoom interview coming up for a 4-year college position. What questions can I ask to the search committee?

The questions period in a job interview is often used by people to show their genuine interest in the position and the institution, but please try to avoid brown-nosing and only ask things that are genuinely of interest to you.  There is an expectation that you will already have read the institution/department website/reports so you should already have a strong command of information in these materials and only ask about things that go beyond this information.  Here are some potential questions that might (or might not) be of interest to you:

Can you tell me a little about the culture of your department?

How collegial have you tended to find the allocation of teaching responsibilities in your department?

For an academic coming in at my level, what kind of service appointments would be typical in the department?  Do you have any particular committees/positions in mind for the appointed candidate?

Does your department have any emerging research interests on the horizon that are not reflected in your existing research reports?

In your experience, what are the main things that have determined the success or failure of your other tenure-track academics in gaining tenure?


These are just some examples of things that might affect your work enjoyment at a new institution, and which are things that are hard to determine from reading reports from the institution.  There are many other things that might be of interest but hopefully this gives you a flavour of the kinds of questions you might fruitfully ask.
